# jqxcalendar in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, jqwidget

im trying to implement a 3rd party plugin , jqWidgets-Calendar(http://www.jqwidgets.com/) into my ionic app. Everything seems good however the calendar could not be use in touch screen devices. When i remove the ionic framework, and just left the calendar its self, it works perfectly . Can someone help me in this . i really need this plugin in my ionic app. I using html, css and angularjs.

```
My Libs:
<script src="scripts/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ionic/ionic-angular.js"></script>
    <!--jqwidgets For Calendar-->
    <link href="css/jqwidgets/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/jqwidgets/jqx.energyblue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="scripts/jqwidgets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jqwidgets/jqxcalendar.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jqwidgets/jqxdatetimeinput.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jqwidgets/jqxtooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jqwidgets/globalize.js"></script>
     <script src="scripts/jqwidgets/jqxangular.js"></script>

My Interface Codes :

<script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/schedule.html">
        <ion-view title="Scheduler">
            <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                <button class="button button-positive icon ion-plus" style=" border-radius:25px;"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
            <ion-content padding="true">

                <div >
                    <jqx-Calendar jqx-settings="calendarSettings"></jqxCalendar>
                    </div>

                <div class="bar bar-header bar-calm">
                    <h1 class="title">{{todayString }}{{date | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy'}}</h1>
                </div>
                <ion-list ng-repeat="item in items" ui-sref="tabs.map({appt: $index})">
                    <ion-item class="item-icon-right">
                        {{item.name}}
                        <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i>
                        <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled">
                        </ion-delete-button>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-view>
    </script>

My Controller : 
         app.controller('CalendarController', function ($scope, ApptListService)     {
        $scope.items = ApptListService.appts(); // populate list

               $scope.calendarSettings = {
                   height: '350px',
                   theme: 'energyblue',
                   enableHover:true,
                   showFooter:true,
                   enableViews:true,
                   enableTooltips:true
                }


$scope.todayString = "(Today)";


$scope.date = new Date();

    });
```

Comment: Hi Marc! You could make it work in Ionic? I'm trying to make it implement in Ionic project.